# How to copy dynamically allocated memory from device to host?

Tags: cuda

I have a memory allocated on device using malloc() function.
I want to copy it to host.
What I am doing right now is 
cudaMemcpy( dst, src, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)
where dst is destination on host and src is pointer to memory allocated in kernel with malloc.
This does not work, and cudaMemcpy return 0xb which translates to: "invalid argument".

Comment: Can you show some code that reproduces that error? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This isn't supported. You cannot copy from allocations on the runtime heap using the host API. You will need to use a copy on the device instead

Comment: @talonmies memcpy on the device side to the host is not supported

Comment: @talonmies Is the answer from the linkt you provided still update? It concerns cuda 4 or 5 and last reply was in 2012? I am using cuda 7.5

Comment: A pointer returned by in-kernel `malloc` (or `new`, or in-kernel `cudaMalloc`, for that matter) cannot participate in a host API `cudaMemcpy` call.  The `invalid argument` error is your direct indication of this.

Comment: Yes it is. Nothing has changed